# Responsive Design - Exact mobile/phablet/tablet Devices Dimensions

Tags: css, media-queries

I am creating responsive website using bootstrap and media queries. Thats a good start however, when i shrink my website from a desktop view to a mobile device there are some breakpoints which makes the website looks not that great. Instead of having this issue when i shrink the browser window, are there any specific dimensions that i can target in order to have a responsive website on all devices? If someone knows please be as much detail as possible. I would like to know the exact dimensions of all mobile/phablet/tablet devices, portrait and landscape.

Thanks.

Comment: It's no use to try to cater to specific devices. Screen sizes and dimensions exist in a myriad of varieties. Base your breakpoints on content instead of devices: http://alistapart.com/article/designing-for-breakpoints

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate devices through browser rather than shrinking the window. On Chrome inspect the code (Ctrl+Shift+I) then select Toggle device toolbar. This will allow you to simulate set default devices with sizes.
Hope this will be a good start for you

Answer (score 0):

There are so many devices with variety in term of screen resolution. If you using Bootstrap (BS), it's better to follow their media queries for styling in some key breakpoints only, note that BS library used mobile-first approach so mostly you will see the @mdia min-width. Refer to below SCSS code from BS.

```css
// Small screen / tablet
$screen-sm:                  768px !default;
$screen-sm-min:              $screen-sm !default;

// Medium screen / desktop
$screen-md:                  992px !default;
$screen-md-min:              $screen-md !default;

// Large screen / wide desktop
$screen-lg:                  1200px !default;
$screen-lg-min:              $screen-lg !default;

/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

More information, [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)